# Java library to generate URLs from a pattern

Tags: java, url

I want to know if there is any free Java library to automate the following process:
1) One provides an URL that follows a specific pattern, e.g.

```
http://www.asite.com/path/to/something/thischange/alsothischange-andthischangetoo
```

where one specify from the above string that:

- `thischange` is an integer defined within range [0-10];
- `alsothischange` is a month, then is in set {jan, ...., dec};
- `andthischangetoo` is an integer defined in range [0-1000];

2) Given a pattern, the library generates all the possile URLs, e.g.

```
http://www.asite.com/path/to/something/0/jan-0
http://www.asite.com/path/to/something/1/jan-0
http://www.asite.com/path/to/something/2/jan-0
...
```

Obviously, I can develop the code by myself, but if there is something available would be better.

Comment: This is about 6 lines of code; do you really need a library for this?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you seem to forget URI templates (RFC 6570), see my answer

Comment: @fge: I'm not sure the existence of that negates the point I was making ;)  The example code in your answer looks just as "complex" as if you were doing this in pure Java...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth this is a point of not reinventing the wheel ;) RFC 6570 exists, there is an implementation of it ;) I'd have answered the same had the implementation not been mine :p

Comment: @OliCharlesworth 6 lines of code? No, I do not agree! Suppose that there is a library capable of handling various type of pattern types (months, days, numbers, etc.) and that this library supports also multi-languages. I will not waste my time by doing something that already exists.

Comment: Downvoter, please, (seriously) motivate your downvote.

Comment: @mat_boy: It's a 3D loop and a call to `String.format`; it's not going to be much more than 6 lines.  And maybe there is such a library that reduces the amount of code you need, but I doubt it...  (FYI, was not my downvote ;) )

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Mine was just an example, not my real case. I have to load multiple patterns from input files, and I prefer to focus my code on the core, not on utility libraries: this is an utility for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am the author, but...

You can try [this library](https://github.com/fge/uri-template). It is an implementation of RFC 6570 (URI templates). In all fairness, I should mention that there exists [another implementation](https://github.com/damnhandy/Handy-URI-Templates), which has a nicer API but a lot more dependencies (mine only depends on Guava).

Let's say you have variables `int1`, `int2`, `month`, your template would be:

```
http://www.asite.com/path/to/something/{int1}/{month}-{int2}
```

Using the library, you can do something like this:

```
// Since the lib depends on Guava, might as well use that
final List<String> months = ImmutableList.of("jan", "feb", "etc");

// Create the template
final URITemplate template 
    = new URITemplate("http://www.asite.com/path/to/something/{int1}/{month}-{int2}");

// Variable values
VariableValue int1, month, int2;

// Expansion data
Map<String, VariableValue> data;

// Build the strings
for (int i1 = 0; i1 <= 10; i1++)
    for (final String s: months)
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= 1000; i2++) {
            int1 = new ScalarValue(Integer.toString(i1));
            month = new ScalarValue(s);
            int2 = new ScalarValue(Integer.toString(i2));
            data = ImmutableMap.of("int1", int1, "month", month, "int2", int2);
            // Print the template
            System.out.println(template.expand(data));
        }
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: the `.expand()` method returns a `String`, not a `URI` or a `URL`. The reason is that while the RFC guarantees expansion results, it cannot guarantee that the resulting string is actually a URI or URL. You'll have to turn that string into what you want by yourself.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Why I should implement a lot of code if someone else already did it! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome ;) The real problem here is that RFC 6570 is not well known... And a pain to implement (I can tell :p)

Comment: So, you can figure out why I was looking for a library!