# Valid URI results in Content-Length: -1

Tags: java, rest, jersey, uri

Since Java 7u21 I stumbled on some strange behavior in a JavaFX applet I made.

On the server side I have a Glassfish 3 server and a mysql database. On the client side I use Jersey to fetch data from the db by sending requests to my Glassfish server. Everything works when I start the program through the JAR file, however when I start it through my JNLP file, I notice some strange behaviour since 7u21. Let me try to show you:

I do a simple request which should give a XML response:

**The method (client):**

```
public List<Users> getUsersHierarchyTreeFilteredByUserlevel(int id, int betweenStart, int betweenEnd) throws UniformInterfaceException {
    WebResource resource = webResource;
    resource = resource.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("users/{0}/hierarchy", String.valueOf(id))).queryParam("start", "" + String.valueOf(betweenStart)).queryParam("end", "" + String.valueOf(betweenEnd));
    System.out.println(resource.getURI());
    return resource.accept(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(new GenericType<List<Users>>() {});
}
```

**The URI**: *System.out.println(resource.getURI());*

```
http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.users/users/4/hierarchy?start=5&end=5
```

**Java console:**

```
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.users/users/4/hierarchy?start=5&end=5, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.users/users/4/hierarchy?start=5&end=5 with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting socket://localhost:8080 with proxy=DIRECT
network: Downloading resource: http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.users/users/4/hierarchy?start=5&end=5
Content-Length: -1
Content-Encoding: null
network: Wrote URL http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.users/users/4/hierarchy?start=5&end=5 to File C:\Users\Steven\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\33\d7edc21-130fad10-temp
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.users/users/4/hierarchy
java.io.IOException: stream is closed
```

As you can see I receive a IOException. This seems to happen at **resource.accept(...)** in the **getUsersHierarchyTreeFilteredByUserlevel(...)** method. However, when I paste the URI in my browser, it shows the correct XML data? I have no idea why... It works when running the JAR itself or with 7u17.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

**Update**
**Fetch with wget (64bit)**

```
D:\>WGET64.EXE -S --http-user=*** --http-passwd=*** "http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.users/users/4/hierarchy?start=5&end=5"
--22:06:53--  http://localhost:8080/myWS/webresources/entities.users/users/4/hierarchy?start=5&end=5
       => `hierarchy@start=5&end=5'
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost[127.0.0.1]:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
 1 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 2 X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)
 3 Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2
 4 Pragma: No-cache
 5 Cache-Control: no-cache
 6 Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
 7 Content-Type: application/xml
 8 Date: Wed, 05 Jun 2013 20:06:53 GMT
 9 Connection: close

    [ <=>                                 ] 9,610         --.--K/s

22:06:53 (9.16 MB/s) - `hierarchy@start=5&end=5' saved [9610]
```

Comment: If you try and fetch the URI with a command-line client (for instance `wget` with the `-S` option), is the content length correct?

Comment: By the way, it seems you want to build URIs from various parameters; in this case, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858145/java-library-to-generate-urls-from-a-pattern/16858647#16858647) can help.

Comment: Hi fge, just did the wget fetch. Added findings to original post.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure there isn't a 401 from you Java code too? Can you try and do a simple main() using another API?

Comment: I'd better use all the right parameters of wget ofcourse. I use BASIC authentication so had to add --http-user and --http-passwd. Anyway, updated the question with the correct wget data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all had to do with the same issues regarding this question:

[Authentication required window popping up after 7u21 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626676/authentication-required-window-popping-up-after-7u21-update)

and follow up question:

[basic authentication fails with glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278303/basic-authentication-fails-with-glassfish)

Answered by dennis-the-menace which you can find here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362271/1527284